# How to create mysql table with column DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in EST ZONE?

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timezone

```
CREATE TABLE tabe_1(
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
A VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
B VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL,
C VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL,
D DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', 'EST5EDT'),
E DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', 'EST5EDT') ,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I used this code but I had an error near CONVERT_TZ(). I expect that CONVERT_TZ() return datetime, but it looks not. I used `CAST(AS DATETIME)` but not working as well!! **MySQL version is 5.7.12**

Answer (score 0):

I'm saving you a world of pain with this answer...

Set everything at the DB layer as UTC. The calculations are much simpler from there for everything from that point forward.

But since you've provided a localised example, I'll answer that too. Basically you need to configure your MySQL Server to use that local timezone, then you can just used the standard syntax of;

```
column_x DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Few handy links

```
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timezone-problems.html
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html
```

Implementation details are hugely dependent on your infrastructure setup though. So you'll need to look for those specific details yourself.

Also a handy link for design patterns for automatically updating database records on both Create and Update records can be found here: https://www.contradodigital.com/2020/04/02/handy-database-design-for-records-to-track-created-date-time-and-updated-date-time/